# Video chat web site

Tags: videochat

I am trying to understand how to build a web-site interface for *videochat*.

- *What are the technologys to use?*
- *Is there a guide about the steps to follow for developement?*

I would prefer not use Flash for this…

Is it possible to do everything in *html5 & Javascript*?